# How to improve the speed of a for loop in PHP?

Tags: php, csv, count, fgetcsv

I have a CSV file with different lines:

```
;0;1;0;4;5;M;468468;A1101;0090
0;1;0;4;5;M;468468;A1108;0090
```

And in a folder of photos that must have the naming format "A1101_0090-1.JPG" for the first view for example.

I wrote a code that allows you to have two things:

- the names of the images present in both the csv file and the photos folder, and the number of views
- The names of images that are in the photos folder but not in the csv file or that are incorrectly renamed.

My script works but when I put a big photo folder with more than 5000 photos for example, the processing is very long... how could I improve my code ?

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
$dataImage = [];
$dataImageTmp = [];
$path = $_POST['path'];

$photos = scandir($path);
$photos = array_map('strtoupper', $photos);

if (($handle = fopen("../RC_PRODUCT_HUB.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $firstLine = true;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 9000000, ";")) !== FALSE){
        if (!$firstLine){
            if ($data[0] != null) {
                $countImage = count(glob($path . $data[6] . '_' . $data[7] . '*.*'));
                for ($i = 0; $i <= $countImage; ++$i) {
                    if ((file_exists($fileName = $path.$data[6].'_'.$data[7].'-'.$i.'.JPG'))){
                        if (!in_array($fileName, $dataImage)){
                            $dataImage[$data[6] . '_' . $data[7]]['file'][$i] = $fileName;
                            $fileName = str_replace($path, '', $fileName);
                            if (!in_array($fileName, $dataImageTmp)){
                                $dataImageTmp[] = $fileName;
                            }
                        }
                        $dataImage[$data[6] . '_' . $data[7]]['TOTAL'] = $countImage;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $firstLine = false;
    } 

    //FIRST PART
    echo count($dataImage)." refs founds.<br>";
    print_r($dataImage).'<br>';

    //SECOND PART

    $dataImageTmp = array_map('strtoupper', $dataImageTmp); 
    $resultat = array_diff($photos, $dataImageTmp);
    $element = '.';
    unset($resultat[array_search($element, $resultat)]);
    $element2 = '..';
    unset($resultat[array_search($element2, $resultat)]);

    echo count($resultat)." photos found.<br>";

    foreach ($resultat as $result) {
        echo ($result) . '<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `glob()` is slow in large folders. Calling it each time through the loop will be slow.

Comment: It won't affect the perormance significantly, but instead of the `$firstLine` variable, just call `fgets()` once before the `while` loop to skip over the header line.

Comment: `$i <= $countImage` should be `$i < $countImage`.

Comment: Does the number at the end of the filename start at 0 or 1?

Comment: Image names start with "-1.JPG "and increment according to the number of frames of the image @Barmar

Comment: If they start at `1`, why do you do `for ($i = 0; ...)`?

Comment: I'm going to change that and make it start at 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `glob()`. Just use a loop that processes each file that matches the pattern in numeric order. You can stop the loop when the file doesn't exist.

I assume there are no gaps in your numeric sequence of filenames.

```
if (($handle = fopen("../RC_PRODUCT_HUB.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    fgets($handle); // skip header line
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 9000000, ";")) !== FALSE){
        if ($data[0] != null) {
            for ($i = 1; file_exists($fileName = $path.$data[6].'_'.$data[7].'-'.$i.'.JPG'); ++$i) {
                if (!in_array($fileName, $dataImage)){
                    $dataImage[$data[6] . '_' . $data[7]]['file'][$i] = $fileName;
                    $fileName = str_replace($path, '', $fileName);
                    if (!in_array($fileName, $dataImageTmp)){
                        $dataImageTmp[] = $fileName;
                    }
                }
                if (isset($dataImage[$data[6] . '_' . $data[7]]['TOTAL'])) {
                    $dataImage[$data[6] . '_' . $data[7]]['TOTAL']++;
                } else {
                    $dataImage[$data[6] . '_' . $data[7]]['TOTAL'] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Another option would be to read the entire directory into the keys of an associative array. Then you can just check whether the filename is in the array, rather than calling `file_exists()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just tested with a folder of 8000 photos and the processing is much faster than before! @Barmar

Comment: Can you help me to invert to get all the csv lines that don't have associated images please? @Barmar

Comment: After the `for` loop, `if ($i == 1) { $lines_with_no_images[] = $data[6] . '_' . $data[7]; }`

Comment: I realized a problem: if it has an image called for example WSR784_0090-3.JPG but there is no WSR784_0090-1.JPG in the folder it displays "no image in the folder". How could I change this so that it says "only 1 view of the image"? @Barmar

Comment: That's what I meant when I wrote "I assume there are no gaps in your numeric sequence". If you need to deal with that, you have to go back to your earlier `glob()` implementation, and live with the performance impact.

Comment: Geez, man... You think there's no way to keep your code by fixing this? @Barmar

Comment: The whole point of my solution was to avoid listing all the matches, by trying each number until it finds a miss. If they're not sequential, that idea fails.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to note:

- Why first `count(glob(..))` and then a loop again to find file names (`file_exists`)? You can just do `glob($path . $data[6] . '_' . $data[7] . '*.JPG')` to get the file names. You solution first creates an array of all file names, counts it and then discards it and creates a whole new array for file names.

  You can iterate over the array returned by `glob`, then extract `$i` from file name if you need it.
- If you need that `count(glob(..))`, you can replace it by shell commands. I think they would be faster, because they don't need memory allocation/deallocation in PHP.

  Something like `shell_exec("ls '{$path}{$data[6]}_{$data[7]}*.*' | wc -l")`. Of course this is for *nix based systems and `bash/sh`. You can find similar things for other OS (or shells).
- You can split your file somehow, and use multiple scripts to process them. This solution can vary a lot depending on how complex you want to be. Like:

  - Splitting csv file beforehand, then run your script on them, then merge results.
  - Write a script to read csv and run multiple processes, giving some parts of csv file to each process to process, then merge results. [Process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#installation) or similar libraries can be useful here.
  - Use a job queue. A script reads the csv file and creates a job for each line (maybe not every line, but like every 100 line). Jobs are processed by multiple workers and results are saved in a DB or something to merge. There are some solutions, but I only used them in frameworks like Laravel or Symfony which have their own job queue. Search for `php job queue` and you will find some solutions.

Comment: I doubt very much that parsing a shell command will be better than a built-in function.

Comment: I don't doubt it very much, but I can't say for sure. Has to be tested though, and that's why I wrote I think.